# Is it true that $a$ and $b$ should be disjoint permutations?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $a,b \in S_n$ and $ab=ba$ and $b$ moves some points that not moved by $a$. Is it true that $a$ and $b$ should be disjoint permutations?

EDIT:
We can consider $b=a^kc$ where $a$ and $c$ are disjoint, to construct a counterexample class. Do you know other constructions?

Comment: make a search about "centrilizer of an element in $S_n$", you will find what you want

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(1,2)(3,4)$.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by ``disjoint permutation", but maybe $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(1,2)(3,4)$ (in $S_4$ for example) is a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a cycle $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ a product of $\,a\,$ with a cycle disjoint from it.

Comment: Excellent! We can consider $b=a^kc$ where $a$ and $c$ are disjoint, to construct more general class. Do you know other constructions?

Comment: @user153200 Yes: $a$ and $b$ commute iff $b$ centralizes $a$, and we can describe the centralizer of a permutation [explicitly](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208790/centralizer-of-a-given-element-in-s-n) in terms of its disjoint cycle representation. This gives not just any class of examples - it exhausts all of them. One small subclass of this is the permutations which can be written as products of powers of $a$'s cycles and any permutation disjoint from $a$.